# How to position the arrow according to list clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I working on with a markup which is a kind of menu. So this is my query I have `ul li` on my webpage. When we about to click it will show different content on its right like a popup. Everything goes well except my arrow. My arrow needs to position to the center of `li` when I click the element rather here the arrow shows on different position. Could anyone help me how to fix this one.

**Markup**

```
<ul>
    <li>text1</li>
    <li>text2</li>
    <li>text3</li>
    <li>text4</li>
    <li>text5</li>
    <li>text6</li>
    <li>text7</li>
    <li>text8</li>
</ul>
<div class='test'>
   <div class='arrow'></div>
<div class='test-con'>
<p> sample text sample text sample text sample text sample text sample text sample text sample text sample textsample text sample text sample text sample text sample text sample text sample text sample textsample text sample text sample text sample textsample text sample text sample text sample text sample text sample text sample text sample text sample text sample text sample text sample text sample text sample text sample text</p></div>
</div>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$('ul li').click(function () {
    $('.test').show();
});
$('ul,.test').click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $('html').click(function () {
        $('.test').hide();
    });
});
```

NOTE : The `UL` I am having here will scroll to show different menu so the arrow needs to place accordingly.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/y67cksp0/6/)**

**THANKS IN ADVANCE**

Comment: @KK my bad forgot to post demo. You can find the demo now in my updated question

Comment: what you have tried to achieve this... show that code too

Comment: @anni demo is already in my question

Comment: noo... i mean, you want ot position that arrow, so what code you have written by yourself to position that arrow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you're looking for something like this:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/y67cksp0/9/)

The trick is to add the following in **$('ul li').click(function(){})**:

```
$('.arrow').css("top",$(this).offset().top+6);
```

EDIT:

Problem solved:

[New DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/y67cksp0/12/)

[Final DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/y67cksp0/15/)  :P

Comment: Will we able to bind the position on scroll so that it stick to li when its scroll

Comment: check the edit to my answer. Here's your request: http://jsfiddle.net/y67cksp0/12/

Comment: Dude i feel like asking one more favor with this will you.

Comment: Its like when the li scrolls to the top it seem weird that arrow goes with it so the li needs to stop scroll once it reaches the top offset of `ul`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61419/discussion-between-benjamin-and-nikunj).

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

**JS:**

```
$('ul li').click(function () {
    var p = $(this).offset().top; //Get offset
    $('.test .arrow').css('top', p + 'px'); //Set offset
    $('.test').show(); //finally show
});
$('ul,.test').click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $('html').click(function () {
        $('.test').hide();
    });
});
```

You might need to make some adjustments.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/y67cksp0/7/

Comment: Will we able to bind the position on scroll so that it stick to li when its scroll

Comment: Yes, you can. You'll have to modify your code. You need to add some flag to identify the current active li. and bind event to scroll so that it adjusts the position of arrow according to the position of active li.

Comment: Iam newbie will me help me with the scracth

Comment: You can refer nikunj scroll code for that. Exactly what I was talking

Answer (score -1):

what about changing the top to 50%

```
.test > .arrow {
   /*display: none;*/
    top: 50%;
...
}
```

Comment: Need to be center of the li when each and every li is clicked